# AzureML web service error

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I try to implement random forest classifier in AzureML using Python script. It ran well in experiment but I am facing error when test the web services.

```
# The script MUST contain a function named azureml_main
# which is the entry point for this module.

# imports up here can be used to 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# The entry point function can contain up to two input arguments:
#   Param<dataframe1>: a pandas.DataFrame
#   Param<dataframe2>: a pandas.DataFrame
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):

    label_x = dataframe1[['NSP']]
    del dataframe1['NSP']

    label_y = dataframe2[['NSP']]
    del dataframe2['NSP']
    trained_model = random_forest_classifier(dataframe1, label_x)
    # print ("Trained model :: ", trained_model)
    predictions = trained_model.predict(dataframe2)


    # print ("Train Accuracy :: ", accuracy_score(label_x, trained_model.predict(dataframe1)))
    print ("Test Accuracy  :: ", accuracy_score(label_y, predictions))
    # print (" Confusion matrix ", confusion_matrix(dataframe2, predictions))
    cm = confusion_matrix(label_y, predictions)
    TP = cm[0][0]
    FP = cm[0][1]
    FN = cm[1][0]
    TN = cm[1][1]
    print("True Positive: ", TP, "False Positive: ", FP, "True Negative: ", TN, "False Negative: ",FN)
    # If a zip file is connected to the third input port is connected,
    # it is unzipped under ".\Script Bundle". This directory is added
    # to sys.path. Therefore, if your zip file contains a Python file
    # mymodule.py you can import it using:
    # import mymodule

    # Return value must be of a sequence of pandas.DataFrame
    return pd.DataFrame(predictions)

def random_forest_classifier(features, target):
    """
    To train the random forest classifier with features and target data
    :param features:
    :param target:
    :return: trained random forest classifier
    """
    clf = RandomForestClassifier()
    clf.fit(features, target)
    return clf
```

[image: AzureML]

When I test the web services by entering the values, it show this error.

> 85: Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information: ---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ---------- Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last): File "\server\InvokePy.py", line 120, in executeScript outframe = mod.azureml_main(*inframes) File "\temp-6305281036382248739.py", line 52, in azureml_main File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 498, in predict proba = self.predict_proba(X) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 537, in predict_proba X = self._validate_X_predict(X) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 319, in _validate_X_predict return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 365, in _validate_X_predict X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr") File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 407, in check_array context)) ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 21)) while a minimum of 1 is required. ---------- End of error message from Python interpreter ----------, Error code: ModuleExecutionError, Http status code: 400, Timestamp: Thu, 07 Dec 2017 15:24:18 GMT

Can anyone tell me where is the error?

Comment: is this the error? `ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 21)) while a minimum of 1 is required.`

Comment: what is the cause of this error?

Comment: I think you're passing an empty array to a predict() method. Try printing the arrays to see what they look like before they are passed. Nb it may be easier to debug using an IDE like jupyter. You can run jupyter from within your Azure ML workspace.